# Android tabhost with asynchronous HttpClient

Tags: android, asynchronous, httpclient, android-tabhost

I have an application with tabs and every tab has HttpCLient that is triggered every time user clicks on the tab and a page is downloaded in a tabActivity thread. When user clicks on tab and then switches to another one, he must wait for a few seconds, so that the request will be sent to server and reply received. I want to make switching between the tabs asynchronous from the HttpClients. It did not work even when i put requests in threads and it even did not work when I introduced TabGroupActivity on every tab.
I have a separate class with all the requests to the server. SHould i extend this class with asyncTask? (This is actually the last thing i have been thinking about that could help)

---

**EDIT:**
On every tab onPause i am doing Thread.join() nad it seems that it is the action that slows down all the process of comming back to the same tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent UI from blocking, all potentially slow running operations (such as networking) should run in the background, e.g. via some way of concurrency such as Asynctask.

I think Asynctask is better choice (comparing with threading) because it encapsulate everything into a single class, and is native android. (e.g. you don't need to use RunOnUIThread when using this class)

read this article for more information: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html